# Why is pan (and zoom) not working on my Chart.js graph?

Tags: chart.js, hammer.js

I'm making a linear graph and the pan and zoom functionality are not working.
I'm using:

```
"chart.js": "Chart-js#v2.5.0",
"chartjs-plugin-zoom": "Chart.Zoom.js#v0.7.0",
"hammerjs": "v2.0.8"
```

and added them in this orden in the html:

```
<script src="~/lib/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/chartjs-plugin-zoom/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using chart.js 2.5.0 because i needed it to work on IE11 and read somewhere that it was better to use that version, but I'm not sure about that.

I copied a working code from snippets online, but it's still now working.

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="180"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 0, 5, 9, 4, 11]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                pan: {
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: 'x',
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: 'x',
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The graph shows but I'm not getting the functionalities and in the console there are no errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I created a fiddle from your code and see the zoom is working correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/b3yvamed/

Comment: yeah... but it's not working on my ASP.NET MVC project  @kunal-khivensara

Comment: See if you have any error in the console.

Comment: No, I don't... @KunalKhivensara

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version of ChartJS, at the moment 3.7.1.
If your downloaded scripts don't load, it could be a bug with IE11.
For me zooming works, but panning doesn't. (It is already an issue [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/issues/53)